# Adding tags to EC2 AWS lambda backup script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, boto3

I am trying to add a tag to an AWS lambda function which creates AMIs of EC2 instances. Below is the lambda function I am using:

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime
import sys
import pprint

ec = boto3.client('ec2')
retention_days = 7
def lambda_handler(event, context):

reservations = ec.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['backup', 'Backup', 'Client']},
    ]
).get(
    'Reservations', []
)
print (reservations)
instances = sum(
    [
        [i for i in r['Instances']]
        for r in reservations

    ], [])

print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)

to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

for instance in instances:
        name_tag = [
            str(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
            if t['Key'] == 'Name'][0]
        print (name_tag)
        print ("check_loop")

        create_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        create_fmt = create_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        AMIid = ec.create_image(InstanceId=instance['InstanceId'], Name="Lambda12 - " + instance['InstanceId'] + " " + name_tag +" from " + create_fmt, Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance['InstanceId'] + " " + name_tag + " from " + create_fmt, NoReboot=True, DryRun=False)
        to_tag[retention_days].append(AMIid['ImageId'])

        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')


        instancename = ''
        for tags in instance["Tags"]:
            if tags["Key"] == 'Client':
                print ("This is instance inside if with key" + tags["Key"])
                instancename = tags["Value"]
                print ("This is instancename" + instancename )
                ec.create_tags (
                    DryRun=False,
                    Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
                    Tags=[
                          {'Key': 'Client', 'Value': instancename},
                    ]
                )
            print "This is last instancename" + instancename

        ec.create_tags(
            Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
            Tags=[
                    {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
                ]
        )


        print ("Name tag " + name_tag)
        print ("check_loopend")
```

Now the issues I am facing in this code is related to this part:

```
instancename = ''
    for tags in instance["Tags"]:
        if tags["Key"] == 'Client':
            print ("This is instance inside if with key" + tags["Key"])
            instancename = tags["Value"]
            print ("This is instancename" + instancename )
            ec.create_tags (
                DryRun=False,
                Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
                Tags=[
                      {'Key': 'Client', 'Value': instancename},
                ]
            )
        print "This is last instancename" + instancename
```

I want to add tags to AMIs when the instance has tag of the format:

```
{'Key': 'Client', 'Value': 'XYZ'}
```

Where XYZ is the value.

But somehow when the above loop ends, all my instances are getting tagged with the value which comes at the last iteration of the loop.

Ex.

instance 1 - `{'Key': 'Client', 'Value': 'ABC'}`
instance 2 - Key doesn't exists
instance 3 - `{'Key': 'Client', 'Value': 'XYZ'}`

At the end of these three, all the respective AMIs are getting tagged with:
`{'Key': 'Client', 'Value': 'XYZ'}`

Is there anything I am missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. - There is no indentation issue at the start of the code.

Comment: What is your actual problem ?

Comment: Have a look at Example section. My problem is in the loop where I am supposed to add tags `{'Key': 'Client', 'Value': instancename}`. All the AMIs are getting tagged with the a single value of `instancename` variable.

Answer (score 0):

As I used a very similar script for my backups I can comment -

You are setting you variable in the loop for devices and then doing the tagging by groups of instances that have the same retention period. SO you get the last update to the variable instancename and are updating all of the instances (assuming most share a retention schedule) at once.